# C# Array Issues; Can't Save Array Index to a Variable

Tags: c#, arrays

So I have this code here that's supposed to detect whether or someone is a male or female. Essentially, we have a piece of software that connects us to different people on the phone and their name is readily available. What this should (in theory) do is detect the person's name and gender in the array and input it into our form. I have included a little sample of the code here, specifically the part that isn't working and I was wondering if any of you have any clue why this is the case.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace GenderChecker
{
class Class
{

    public static void Check(string stringy)
    {
        int gender = 0;
        string[] arrayexample = { "Example One Male", "Example Two Female" };
        if (arrayexample.Contains(stringy))
        {
            int arrayPosition = arrayexample.IndexOf(arrayexample, stringy); //part that doesn't work
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        genderChecker("Example One");
    }
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me a different way to save the array position as an integer because this code doesn't work at all and it's a bit infuriating.

Thank you,
MTS

Comment: What is names in  `names.IndexOf(arrayexample, stringy);`?

Comment: Whoops, that was from the unedited code. I'll fix the OP, just a second.

Comment: With your code as posted, the "part that doesn't work" line will never get hit, because your array doesn't contain the string `"Example One"` as one of its elements (so your Contains call will never return true).

Comment: "Example One Male" is in there, I'm pretty sure it should detect that it contains "Example One" and move on...?

Comment: ...Why would you think that? Read the documentation. `Array.Contains` returns true if one of the array elements equals the value you're passing in. None of the array elements equal `"Example One"`.

Comment: Could you post an answer with exactly how it should be written out? I know it's a bit much to ask, but I'm a bit new to C# and I would just rather see it in the big picture than just a little snippet of text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IndexOf() is a static method on the Array class.

do this instead:

```
arrayPosition = Array.IndexOf(arrayexample, stringy);
```

if the string isn't in the array, it will return -1

Answer (score 1):

Your code will loop over twice; wouldn't you be better off using a for loop?

```
public static void Check(string stringy)
{
    int gender = 0;
    string[] arrayexample = { "Example One Male", "Example Two Female" };
    var arrayPosition = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayexample.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arrayexample[i] == stringy)
        {
        arrayPosition = i;
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful How do you think Array.IndexOf is implemented?  And Array.Contains?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful If you think about how IndexOf and Contains must be implemented you will understand why I said that.

Comment: To be fair, he could also just use IndexOf by itself, since it'll return -1 if the value isn't found.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked OP's `Contains()` method! Sorry.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful No worries.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Check(string stringy)
    {
        int gender = 0;
        string[] arrayexample = { "Example One Male", "Example Two Female" };
        for(int I=0;i<arrayexample.Length;i++)
        {
          if (arrayexample[i].Contains(stringy))
          {
            int arrayPosition = i; //part that doesn't work
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And if you initialize I at anything but 0, you miss comparing "Example One Male" because it's at index 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
There is no need to include the array parameter within Indexof

int arrayPosition = arrayexample.IndexOf(stringy);

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you're not actually trying to find a string in an array. What you're *actually* trying to do is map a string to a gender. You're using entirely the wrong tool for that task (and making your life difficult). Dictionaries map values to other values; they're what you need.

```
public enum Gender { Male, Female }
private Dictionary<string, Gender> _mapping = new Dictionary<string, Gender> {
    ["Name One"] = Gender.Male,
    ["Name Two"] = Gender.Female,
};
// now do something with _mapping[name]
```

Comment: Hm, well, the comments also suggest he expected to make partial matches, in which case a dictionary won't help much.